# background-size is not working on FF; doesn't show the CSS image?

Tags: css, firefox

I've a big image to fit in the middle of a login screen. It shows ok with IE10 and Chrome. But it doesn't show anything on Firefox (36.0.1).

[image]

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 401px) {
    body {
        background: url("../../Content/images/Eplod Login DrillBit.png") center no-repeat #2b984b;                                 
        background-size: auto 90%;
        -moz-background-size: auto 90%;
        -webkit-background-size: auto 90%;
        background-origin: content-box;                
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background: url("../../Content/images/Eplod Login DrillBit.png") center no-repeat #2b984b;                                    
        background-size: 600px;
        -moz-background-size: 600px;
        -webkit-background-size: 600px;
        background-origin: content-box;
    }
}
```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. In the Mozilla Developer Network it shows the way of using [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size); I've put every elements individually rather than short hand. But nothing working and I'm now puzzled. For screen size bigger than 401px doesn't show any image. But for screen 400px or smaller it shows the image but wrongly.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: When using browser-specific styles (i.e. the prefixed rules you use) place them *before* the W3C standard! Also, are you sure you didn't mean `90% auto`, instead of `auto 90%`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come Firefox can't read an image path with a space when placed inside css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464295/how-come-firefox-cant-read-an-image-path-with-a-space-when-placed-inside-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/2avd2kvg/).

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url("http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/camel/camel-06.jpg") center no-repeat #2b984b;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        /* -moz-background-size: 90% auto;
        -webkit-background-size: 90% auto; */
        background-size: 90% auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) {
    body {       
        /* -moz-background-size: 600px;
        -webkit-background-size: 600px; */
        background-size: 600px;
    }
}
```

What I did:

- Turned the values around: set a responsive, percentual width on small window sizes (max-width: 400px) and a fixed size on larger screens. Though I would recommend setting the break-point to the size of your background-size. (Give or take a few pixels)
- Moved shared properties into `body` outside a media query
- Changed the values of background-size in the first media query: first comes the width: 90% and then comes to height: auto. The background image will thus always be 90% of its parent with an automatic height.
- Put the prefixed lines (browser specific) before the un-prefixed lines (W3C standard) as you should. Browsers should always use the latest implementation of technology, which in cases like these are the un-prefixed ones. Background-size is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts), though, so I don't think you need any prefixes at all.

Comment: Your solution actually worked after changing couple of things. Thank you very much mate. (y)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bram Vanroy. Your solution actually worked after changing couple of things. Here are the codes worked for me.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    max-height: 90%;
    background: url("../../Content/images/Eplod Login DrillBit.png") center no-repeat #2b984b;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

@@media screen and (min-width: 401px) {
    body {
        background-size: auto 90%;
        -moz-background-size: auto 90%;
        -webkit-background-size: auto 90%;
        background-origin: content-box;
    }
}

@@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-size: 600px;
        -moz-background-size: 600px;
        -webkit-background-size: 600px;
        background-origin: content-box;
    }
}
```